# Linux / cPanel security - firewall or Denyhosts?

Tags: linux

I have a VPS running cPanel that has a csf firewall configured.

I've also got Host Access Control (does this mean denyhosts on cPanel?) as well as cPHulk which is a cPanel exclusive utility.

My question is whether it is better to use the firewall or use denyhosts or cPHulk ... and can I/should I use any of these in combination with each other?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, csf firewall has lfd which works as an automatic "deny hosts" by scanning logs and blocking
IPs that fail authentication to variuos services (included mod_security). It's *highly* configurable
in every aspect.

In every cPanel server we manage we disable cpHulk and use exclusively csf+lfd.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that - yes csf does look very configurable.